# Edited Questions Queue Link

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, tag-disambiguation, rate-limiting

Recently I went through a bunch of questions which were missing our open-source project tag and 'suggested an edit'. It looks like I have reached a limit on those as I get a message my queue is full.

Is there a way for me to send a link with all the edited questions to another Stack Overflow user with big reputation so that 'super-user' can approve the changes and therefore unblocks me to edit more questions?

Comment: In general, it's best to just wait for the queue to get worked through naturally. It may take a bit, but it'll happen. The Suggested Review queue on Stack Overflow is very often full/ close to full.

Comment: Looking at your profile, it looks like you've reached the maximum of 5 pending edit suggestions. Just be patient, it'll come around.

Comment: Thanks for that. Good answers. BTW I am puzzled by down-votes on this question - is it not a legit or well formed question which adds value?

Comment: Umm.... you didn't even remove what you consider to be the *wrong* tag, [[tag:uno]], in these edits: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29289470, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29289497, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29289467 ? That's not useful at all.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408887/792066

Comment: @CodyGray - Good point; will be removing 'uno' as well moving forward.

Answer (score 4):

Don't make edits like that.  Adding a new tag without addressing any other issues in the post is not the way to maximize the usage of the review queue.

Maybe there's some *other* discussion to be had about synonymizing [uno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uno) and [uno-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uno-platform), or even if they're *related* (doesn't look like they are), or why people are mistagging things, but that shouldn't be discussed in the form of edits in the review queue, that should be discussed on Meta.

Comment: Interesting take. I will see how to do it better next time. Unfortunately 'uno' is a very generic word and as-is it applies not only to general language but at least two other products, or sub-product names. Hence, being more specific and saying "uno-platform" makes a difference. I don't think that making a synonym is going to make things better or easier to find. Continuous feedback to those asking uno-platform questions to tag it appropriately will solve a problem on the long term.

Comment: Not "maybe"; *definitely*. Before you go on a mass tagging spree, you need to raise a discussion on Meta.

Comment: @sasha_krsmanovic:  The first step to try and disambiguate what "uno" means is here:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408887/1079354.  This is at least a good starting point for establishing what the actual scope of the question(s) are or should be, and  should be how it's approached to begin with.

Comment: @Makoto - thanks - I added description for Uno Platform

Comment: On *that* post @sasha_krsmanovic, it's not really that valuable.  It's talking about the uno tag and libreoffice-uno tags, which is a common source of amibiguity, and the uno-framework portion is actually not material at that point.  This has to happen in order, and the uno platform is going to have to wait just a *wee* bit.