# Rename [uno] to [libreoffice-uno]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are a couple of uno's:

1. The card game
2. The [framework for LibreOffice modules](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/tools.html)
3. [Some Arduino board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) (based on [a microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328))
4. A [multiplatform code translator](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/doc/articles/intro.md) (?)

It seems like askers are using the [uno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uno) to mean any of those things. There were at least five questions about the card game that had that tag removed, and someone is trying to retag the code translator ones. Can we rename this tag to avoid this problem? All other usages has their own tag (except the card game which doesn't need one).

Comment: *"except the card game which doesn't need one"* ... wow, actually this is the only valid reason to have an "uno" tag. But all jokes aside, after renaming the tag, the tag "uno" could be blocked from being recreated and misused again?

Comment: @Tom unless it becomes a problem, I don't see any point on doing so. Just let it burn

Comment: In case of our open-source project, the official, and trademarked name is "Uno Platform" and it is a UI platform for delivering multi-platform applications - https://github.com/unoplatform   . However, developers often use shortened slang and in informal speach they say "Uno". Unfortunately this informal speech also makes its way to stackoverflow tags, and in turn those questions get missed by our contributors and community.

Comment: yeah, let it burn after renaming. Otherwise, we risk synonymizing it and then get questions blatantly mistagged, which admittedly is even worse. Also, we have [tag:arduino-uno] for the Arduino one.

Comment: all right, all instances of [tag:uno] <-> [tag:arduino-uno] retagged and edited, #3 can be crossed off the list

Comment: There is an existing [tag:uno-platform] tag.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm "All other usages has their own tag" ;)

Comment: "except the card game which doesn't need one" https://i.imgur.com/yXEiYQ4h.jpg

Comment: Is OpenOffice's UNO interface the same/compatible with LibreOffice's? Both say that it stands for "unified network objects," so maybe the tag should be named that.

Comment: @sasha_krsmanovic: The next time you chose a project name, I suggest picking a less ambiguous one.

Comment: *"There were at least five questions about the card game that had that tag removed"* - wait... what? There were/are questions about the uno card game on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Gimby about creating a uno game, but as we know, programming doesn't care about the specific game name, just the implementation.

Comment: @jpmc26 Last I checked, there was no on-going code sharing between LibreOffice and Apache OpenOffice, due to different choices of license, and generally not a lot of warm feelings between the two groups. It's also been 7 years since the last "feature" release of AOO, in which time LO has had about 15 new versions. So I imagine they'll be compatible to the extent that they were forked from the same code base, and incompatible to whatever extent LO has changed things since.

Comment: `programming doesn't care about the specific game name` Why not? We have a [tag:tic-tac-toe] tag, why not an Uno tag?

Comment: @NickODell another tag for trogdor :) (a bad tag doesn't excuse the creation of another bad one)

Comment: @Braiam board game burnination requests [were declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273085/11407695) before :(

Comment: @OlegValter I want to believe that we learned how to do better since '13

Comment: @Braiam heh, try to burn one, then :) I am with you on this one, though - there is no reason to keep tags named after board games. If anything, they only lead to more work for us later when someone decides to name their project/library/framework similarly.

Comment: @OlegValter this one counts? ;) Asking for a friend.

Comment: @Braiam I thought this was a disambiguation request :) Brrr, terms. In the meantime: 16 questions are [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buno%5D+%5Buno-platform%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) with both [tag:uno] and [tag:uno-platform], wading through now.

Comment: @OlegValter well, the end result is the tag being eliminated too. Some people (not me) think that replacing a tag with other is also a burnination. (For me burnination is total tags - 1)

Comment: @Braiam - I was joking :) RE: [tag:uno]+[tag:uno-platform] eliminated, I think not much is left before it can be simply renamed.

Answer (score -1):

UNO (Universal Network Objects) is a component model that is shared(*) by LibreOffice and Apache OpenOffice. It is also something that can be used independently of either:

> UNO can be used indenpendently[*sic*] from OpenOffice.org.
>
> <sup>from: https://www.openoffice.org/udk/</sup>

(though given the UNO Runtime Environment (URE) is no longer available as a separate download, this should be taken with a pinch of salt)

For these reasons, I don't think renaming [uno] to [libreoffice-uno] makes sense.

---

<sup>*: I believe this sharing is primarily due to the common history, not a form of active code sharing</sup>

Comment: I prefer keeping a separate tag for each one. Even if they are kind of the same, the asker is explicitly targeting a host application.

Comment: @Braiam I'm by no means an expert in UNO, but as far as I'm aware, the differences between LibreOffice and OpenOffice when it comes to UNO are minimal, so requiring people to use separate tags seems counter-productive.

Comment: That's fine and all, but plain "uno" is not a good tag. Also, given the bitter feelings on both sides of the LO/OOo I doubt they will be happy with that arrangement. So, explicit tag naming would avoid those two problems.

Comment: OOo uno has it's own tag already: [tag:pyuno]

Comment: @Braiam No it doesn't, that tag is about the Python bindings for UNO. UNO is intended to be usable from multiple programming language (_"Uno offers interoperability between programming languages, other components models and hardware architectures, either in process or over process boundaries, in the Intranet as well as in the Internet. Uno components may be implemented in and accessed from any programming language for which a Uno implementation (AKA language binding) and an appropriate bridge or adapter exists."_)